# How to deal with Firestore returning null values in Map

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making an app using Flutter/Dart and have run into an annoying issue.

When I want to add another variable to an object, such as the `FoodItem` object in this example, and I need to parse the snapshot data into the dart object, the map Firestore returns usually doesn't contain the new value and ends up telling the new object to just make the new variable `null`.

This causes problems throughout the app. How should I approach this without null checking for every single element being parsed? Thanks!

```
class FoodItem with ChangeNotifier {
  String name;
  String barcode;
  String servingSize;
  String calories;
  String totalFat;
  String satFat;
  String transFat;
  String cholesterol;
  String sodium;
  String totalCarbs;
  String protein;
  String fiber;
  String sugar;
  bool new_variable_that_ends_up_null = false;

...

  FoodItem.fromSnapshotData(Map<String, dynamic> data)
      : name = data['Name'],
        calories = data['Calories'],
        barcode = data['Barcode'],
        servingSize = data['Serving Size'],
        totalFat = data['Total Fat'],
        satFat = data['Saturated Fat'],
        transFat = data['Trans Fat'],
        cholesterol = data['Cholesterol'],
        sodium = data['Sodium'],
        totalCarbs = data['Total Carbs'],
        fiber = data['Fiber'],
        sugar = data['Sugar'],
        protein = data['Protein'],
        new_variable_that_ends_up_null = data['New Variable']; // This will return null when it's not already in firstore.
}
```

Comment: Could you paste the data object that you want to actually parse?

Comment: @YakubPasha Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out :

```
new_variable_that_ends_up_null = data['New Variable'] ?? false
```

problem here is u cannot assign `null` to the `bool` it will give u error